# Rango máximo de 60 días en Angular entre dos input de fechas

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sweetalert2

Necesito en JavaScript o TypeScript para Angular que la fecha ingresada de inicio no sea mayor a 60 días para la fecha final ingresada.. la lógica seria: "rango máximo 60 días" entre los dos input (fechaDesde a fechaHasta).

```
datepicker(){
  var dateFrom = this.consultaForm.get('desdeCreacion').value;
  var dateTo = this.consultaForm.get('hastaCreacion').value;

  
  // Rango máximo 60 dias (sweetalert2)
  var dateFrom60 = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(dateFrom).getTime()+5150000000,'yyyy-MM-dd');
  if(dateTo > dateFrom60){
    this.hasta.reset();
    Swal.fire({
      icon: 'error',
      title: 'Rango máximo 60 días'
    })
  }
```

Comment: Podrías usar una biblioteca de manejo de fechas y hacerlo más sencillo https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/differenceInDays

Comment: Has intentado con este ejemplo https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples busca en "Date range picker with custom a selection strategy" en este ejemplo la el rango de la fecha selecionada es -2 +2, al cambiar 0 a 60 deveria fucionar igual como tu quieres